# How can I access saved whiteboards in zoom?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I used the share whiteboard feature in zoom (for Ubuntu). There is a button called "Save":
[image]

I clicked this save-button. Then I ended the zoom meeting.

Where do I find the saved whiteboard? In which folder is it stored (depending on the operating system - e.g. Ubuntu)? Does the graphical user interface of zoom include a button that leads you directly to the stored whiteboards?

I would be happy for any answer that helps me to get back these saved whiteboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 they are stored in `/home/username/snap/zoom-client/75/Documents/Zoom/`

it can also be in
`/scratch/users/username/Documents/Zoom` or `Home/Documents/Zoom` (using Fedora)

In the latest versions of zoom, the folder is opened in a window in the background, when you click "Save". In this folder you find the screenshots of this zoom-call and you check the path.